# trying to obtain number of visitors using gapi deprecated

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I want to display number of visits of my website using google analytics so do that I need to do authentication by google .. it seams that gAPI is no longer used and this is what I get ..

> {"error":"idpiframe_initialization_failed","details":"You have
> created a new client application that uses libraries for user
> authentication or authorization that are deprecated. New clients must
> use the new libraries instead. See the [Migration
> Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration)
> for more information."}..

I'm using angular 15 and this is my code

```js
initGoogleOAuth() {
        const { clientId, apiKey } = environment.googleAnalytics;
    gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': apiKey,
          'discoveryDocs': ['https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta'],
          'clientId': clientId,
          'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
         }).then(() => {
          console.log('test')
          this.getAnalyticsData('2023-01-01','today')
        }).then(function (response:any) {
          console.log(response.result);
        }, function (reason:any) {
          console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(reason));
        });
      }
```

I want to be able to retrieve the number of visitors of my website so what I can use instead of gAPI.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your tags you need to activate `Google Analytics` for your website. From 1th July 2023 Universal Analytics is not going to work so you should use `Goolge Analytics4` or `GA4`.
Have a look at [Google Analytics 4 Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10089681?hl=en) and follow the instructions.